# Apache mod_rewrite to catch XML requests

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

How do I create a apache RewriteRule that catches any request URL ending in .xml, strips off the .xml and passes it to a specific script?

```
http://www.example.com/document.xml, becomes http://www.example.com/document passed to script.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick, I believe.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.xml$ script.php?path=$1
```